# What machine learning model(s) does OverflowAI use?

Tags: support, overflowai

OverflowAI obviously uses machine learning, but what models is it using?

Answer (score 4):

Quoting Prashanth from [the We Are Developers 2023 fireside chat with Joel and Prashanth at 39:53](https://youtu.be/SNVwNKruwTw?t=2393),

> [...] **the OverflowAI for our alpha releases are based on Microsoft Azure's OpenAI APIs** underneath and that's what's powering it because it also comes with some really great guardrails on things like trust and safety as an example, which they've actually done a really good job of. **However, we partner with everybody. We are testing Google's equivalent, we're testing Amazon's open source models, like Mozilla and we've also looked at- if we had our own lightweight model, what would that look like**, and with our own data around it, and the early results of that have been spectacular. Our process AI team and our data team have been testing that very specifically and it's been fascinating to see how much high quality you can get without a lot of uh without a lot of investment.